# How to make "dnf" use packages from a "copr" repository

Tags: fedora, dnf

On Fedora 24:

I want to replace the Haskell compiler (package `ghc`) with a later version (specifically, 7.10.3) from a "copr" repository.

So I enable the repository:

```
dnf copr enable petersen/ghc-7.10.3
```

I can now check the packages available in the copr repository using

```
dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="petersen-ghc-7.10.3" list available
```

`dnf` helpfully shows all the packages, and even marks the packages for which a version has been installed already in blue (if I understand correctly)

One of the packages is for example `ghc.x86_64`.

How do I tell `dnf` to grab the package from the copr repository instead of the default fedora repository?

Comment: Note that I may not yet be up-to-date with all the concepts that come with `dnf`. Arrrr....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the same way you list the packages:

```
dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="petersen-ghc-7.10.3" install ghc
```

Or if you have older version installed, then use `upgrade` instead of `install`. If newer, then `downgrade`. It is all the magic.

Comment: If I do that, `dnf` tells me that I already have lots of conflicting packages ("Skipping packages with conflicts" ... basically all of them). Indeed, I installed the "haskell-platform" package that comes with Fedora earlier. Apparently `dnf` does not consider pulling in stuff from another repository as a conflict-free upgrade. Now, I cannot "throw out" `haskell-platform`, it is not a "group package" but nevertheless just behaves as a marker package that pulls in dependent packages, but install nothing itself. `rpm --erase` on it does not erase the dependent tree... manual work required!.

Comment: Not sure if this means that you already resolved your problems or not. But without knowing how the conflicts look like, I guess there is no way what more information I can provide

Comment: Actually manual work is not required. Simple if one knows how. 1) Recursively remove all the packages pulled in for fedora package `haskell-platform` using `dnf` (instead of `rpm`, which doesn't provide that option): "`dnf erase haskell-platform`" 2) Re-add pcks that might come in handy later: "`dnf install ncurses-c++-libs freeglut-devel`" etc. 3) Just run "`dnf install ghc`". `dnf` will pull the latest `ghc` from the repository `petersen-ghc-7.10.3` (previously enabled) and pull any dependencies from the fedora repo (as that one stays enabled), in my case `ncurses-devel` etc. 4) Win!

Comment: Accepting answer even though the actual is more complex. Thanks Jakuje.